# Auradb using query browser do not have any response from Cypher queries sent from the Brave browser

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-aura

I have created an auradb instance that is managed by Neo4j.

I click "query" in the following interface:
[image]

Then when I provide the credentials to connect to the cypher query interface:
[image]

Then when I try the following simple query it returns with the error:

```
Could not perform discovery. No routing servers available. Known routing table: RoutingTable[database=default database, expirationTime=0, currentTime=1649300786873, routers=[], readers=[], writers=[]]
```

[image]

The same workflow was working perfectly fine a couple of weeks ago.

Can someone help me how to resolve this issue? I want to use the query interface, not the explore interface that connects with bloom (which is working fine).

** Edit: This is possibly an issue with Brave. I am currently running brave version 1.37.111 , where it is not working.

But the same interface worked fine in Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because Brave Shields blocks an important resource, citing CORS.
Disable Shields for https://browser.neo4j.io/ and you should be good to go.
[image]